# More than two periods' hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I want to test more than two periods' income from different goods. I want to know if my new sales strategy has had a significant impact on my income.

Example:

```
        2016     2017    2018   2019    2020

Milk    400$     445$    480$   500$
Fruit   1000$    1200$   700$   1350$
Bakery  500$     650$    800$   910$
        ....     ....    ...    ...     ...
```

Which test is appropriate for a data like this?

Comment: When did your sales strategy come into being? Was it at the same time for all goods?

Comment: My new strategy came into being in 2016. Yes it was at the same time for all goods.

Comment: So do you want to compare only within the period when your strategy was implemented, from 2016 onward? To check if your strategy has produced different results over these specific years? Or do you want to compare your strategy with the previous strategy implemented before 2016, to check if your strategy is better than the old strategy?

Comment: I want to compare only within the period when my strategy was implemented, from 2016 onward. I would like to compare results over these specific years. I mean I want to check if my sales income has increased or not. I have also data for 2015. I would like to check difference between data for 2015 and the other specific years(2016,2017,..... ) too.
 
I need a suitable test for data like this.(Kruskal Wallis, ANOVA(if assumptions is valid) or something different)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comparing the overall trend (from 2016 onward) you could use a linear model, which would give you a slope over the years, which you can also test for significance. The slope would tell you whether the income is changing over time (increasing/decreasing/constant).

You could also include the years before 2016 and include for ex. a dummy variable indicating the old and the new strategy, 1 for years >= 2016, and 0 otherwise. Then with the same linear model you could test whether the average sales are different between these two indicators.

Comment: I have no correlated variables in my dataset. I have only sales income over the years. How can I build a linear model?

Comment: @joshua You mean you have no dependent variables? You do, just not in your current form. Sales is your "y" column, then you have columns for "Year" and "Product". In other words you need to transform your data from wide to long format.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :).

Comment: @joshua Did this answer your question? If so consider accepting this answer to close the matter. If not, is there any other uncertainty?

Comment: I am beginner at stats.exchange.com. I dont have any other uncertainty. How can I accept your answer?

Comment: @joshua By clicking the left arrow to the left of my answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers